# Segment fault when writing to a large 4G dynamic allocating array

Tags: c

In a 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 system, a simple C program allocates a dynamic array larger or equal than 4GB. And when the program tries to write value to each item of the array, a segment fault occurs. Below is the original code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROW 1024 * 1024 
#define COL 1024

#define u32 unsigned int
#define u64 unsigned long

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    u32 count = 0;
    u64* ary = (u64 *)malloc(sizeof(u32) * ROW * COL);
    assert(ary != NULL);
    printf("ary:%p\n", ary);

    for(u32 r = 0; r < ROW; r++) {
        for (u32 c = 0; c < COL; c++) {
            ary[r*ROW + c] = count;
            count++;
        }
    }

    free(ary);
    printf("free array\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Compiles the source as:

`gcc -o t_32_64_ary_64 t_32_64_ary.c -g -std=c99 -m64`

When run it, a segment fault:

```
ary:0x7fa13584b010
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Since the machine has 16GB memory, so I believe it allocates a 4GB memory without any issue.

And if I comment out the write value code as:

```
    /*
    for(u32 r = 0; r < ROW; r++) {
        for (u32 c = 0; c < COL; c++) {
            ary[r*ROW + c] = count;
            count++;
        }
    }
    */
```

The program exits normally as:

```
ary:0x7f136cd85010
free array
```

Which indicates the it allocates a 4GB memory successfully.

Uses valgrind to run the program:

```
valgrind ./t_32_64_ary_64
...
==4830== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x395a5040, 0x1395a5040) (undefined)
ary:0x395a5040
==4830== Invalid write of size 8
==4830==    at 0x4006AE: main (t_32_64_ary.c:21)
==4830==  Address 0x1395a5040 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4,294,967,296 alloc'd
==4830==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4830==    by 0x400648: main (t_32_64_ary.c:14)
==4830== 
==4830== 
==4830== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==4830==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x1395A6000
==4830==    at 0x4006AE: main (t_32_64_ary.c:21)
==4830==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==4830==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==4830==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==4830==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==4830==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==4830== 
==4830== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4830==     in use at exit: 4,294,967,296 bytes in 1 blocks
==4830==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 4,294,967,296 bytes allocated
==4830== 
==4830== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4830==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4830==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4830==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4830==    still reachable: 4,294,967,296 bytes in 1 blocks
==4830==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4830== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==4830== 
==4830== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4830== ERROR SUMMARY: 505 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Based on the information, it seems line:

```
        ary[r*ROW + c] = count;
```

Triggers the segment fault, but I don't understand why. I believe the index: r*RWO+c is in the array range.

Please help and thanks!

Comment: I don't think that  `ary[r*ROW + c] = count;` is the standard way of indexing in C

Comment: I'm trying to simulate a 2 dimensional ary[r][c] accessing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're indexing is wrong, and you're probably not allocating correctly.

You probably want to allocate by doing `malloc(sizeof(u64) * ROW * COL)` (note I used `u64` instead of `u32`). As it currently is, you're only allocating half of the memory you're probably intending to.

You should index by doing `ary[r*COL + c]` (or `ary[c*ROW + r]`, depending on your needs). And you should be using `size_t` instead of `u32` for your index values, to avoid [the overflow issues C_Elegans mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49469091/1287251).

Also, while this isn't causing problems in this small program, you should get in the habit of surrounding your macro definitions with parentheses (e.g. `#define ROW (1024 * 1024)`).

Comment: Thank you! As you points out, I 1) modify the index as `ary[r*COL + c]` 2) uses u64 instead of u32, the program finishes and exit normally. For 1) I didn't notice that my calculation is actually wrong; For 2) it seems to me that due to in 64 bit system, pointer increment is 8-byte instead of 4-byte, so if I use u32, ary[0] to ary[1] will actually be 8-byte, instead of 4-byte I expect.

Answer (score 1):

This line is your main problem:

```
u64* ary = (u64 *)malloc(sizeof(u32) * ROW * COL);
```

You're creating a pointer to `u64` but calculating the size to be allocated based on the size needed for `u32`.

The memory you will get allocated will not be enough for `ROW * COL` number of `u64`'s. It might be only enough for half that number (unless compiling with a compiler that uses the same size for `unsigned int` and `unsigned long`).

---

Edit:

As noted in the other answers, there are more problems with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Using `calloc()` would probably be the more elegant solution for calculating the needed memory. I think it's also a bit less error prone...

```
#define SIZE 0x40000000  // = 1 GiB
uint32_t *array = (uint32_t *)calloc(SIZE, sizeof(uint32_t));
```

Answer (score 0):

The calculations for the number of bytes to allocate in `malloc` is overflowing because `ROW` and `COL` are of type `int` (they're literals). To fix this, you need to declare them as such:

```
#define ROW 1024LL * 1024LL 
#define COL 1024LL
```

Alternatively, consider using `calloc` like so:

```
u64* ary = calloc(sizeof(u64) * COL, ROW); //casting malloc is not recommended in C
```

`calloc` checks for overflow when it multiplies its arguments and always multiplies them as `size_t`, so your multiplication will no longer overflow

Comment: Thank you for you pointing out! With your and @ Cornstalks help, the issue is fixed.